# Is it safe to call an environment variable from a crontab script?

Tags: security, cron, environment-variables

I have a crontab script which read an environment variable with sensitive information(like a decryption key). The crontab entry is defined like that:
`30 3 * * 5 VAR="pw" /usr/bin/script.sh`

Is it safe to store something so sensitive in this way? If not, how can i improve it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Better to read it from a duly protected file.  Environment variables are "open bar".  The location of this file may be in the env var.

Comment: @Jacques No, environment variables are not revealed to other users in any modern unix.

Comment: @Gilles. There are all kinds of processes that may be running in a user environment.  Did you check all the scripts, loggings, etc so that you are sure that this environment variable will not end up accidentally (or not) in some file, print, log etc?

Comment: @Jacques No, but since these processes can also go and read `/path/to/file/containing/the/password` directly, this makes no difference. Things like logs are a secondary path, which I do mention in my answer, and which make environment variables less safe, but the statement that ‘Environment variables are "open bar"’ is unambiguously wrong.

Comment: "open bar" in user's environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting the variable in the crontab file and in the environment is secure in the sense that other users can't access it. However, it runs the risk of accidental disclosure, for example if you post the crontab line when asking for debugging help, or if you copy it and send it to someone as an example of how to automate running the script, or if some process logs its environment and the log is accessible to people who shouldn't have access to this password, or if you back it up and the backups are accessible to people who shouldn't have access to this password. I recommend keeping secrets in a separate file or directory tree and reading them when needed.

If you can't modify `script.sh`:

```
VAR=$(cat ~/.secret/script/password)
```

If you can modify `script.sh`, make it read the variable when it needs it, rather than making it available throughout the script.

Note that while environment variables are not disclosed to other users, command line arguments can be visible to other users through `ps`. So don't pass `$VAR` as an argument to an external command. It's safe to use `$VAR` as an argument to a shell builtin, for example the following is safe:

```
gpg --passphrase-fd=3 3< <(printf %s "$PASSPHRASE")
```

although this specific example would be simpler expressed as

```
gpg --passphrase-file=/path/to/passphrase
```

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot modify the script, so i will move the key into another file as you suggested. IIRC this should be the same way `mysqldump` handle credentials when executing from a backup script.